# Validacion de campos de un form Js

Tags: javascript

Estoy comenzando con js y estoy tratando de hacer la primera validación de un formulario para eso quiero tomar el value de un imput en caso de que no este vació  muestre esta vació en la consola, si no que muestre el value que tiene sin embargo no he podido, (parece que nunca toma los value de que se colocan en los imputs) siempre aparece que el campo esta vació así le escriba texto al input, como podría realizar dicha comprobación y guardar el valor del input? esto es lo que he tratado de hacer hasta el momento:

Gracias por la ayuda

```js
var x = document.getElementById("new_user_name").value;

if(x == ""){
    console.log("esta vacio");
}else {
    console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="users.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lykmapipo/themify-icons@0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="new_user pt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                <!-- nombre, apellido email telefono  -->
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">New User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="new_user_name" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_user_lastname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="new_user_email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="new_user_phone">
                    </div>
                    <button id="new_user_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="user_info_table pt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Last name</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Email</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Phone Nnumber</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class="text-center">
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Mark</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>@mdo</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr class="text-center">
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Jacob</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>@fat</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script src="users.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te aparece el mensaje siempre al cargar la página, no tienes ningún evento asociado a tu botón ni llamas a ninguna función para que se valide nuevamente ese if.

Comment: Si cuando carga la pagina, no hay un evento asociado, trate de usar un change  y parece funcionar pero tendría que usarlo para cada uno de los inputs de manera individual creo yo

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, espero te ayude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es porque no le haz asignado un evento para que sea disparada la acción de tomar el `value` de tu `input`, en la forma que tú tienes el código js esta tomando el valor una vez que carga la página, para que funcione de la forma que tu esperas es agregarle un evento a tu botón con el nombre `submit`:

- Mediante `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){})` indicamos que se ejecutarán las siguientes acciones cuando termine de cargar la página.
- `document.addEventListener('click',function(){})` de esta forma le agregamos el evento al botón con `id new_user_btn`para poder obtener el value del `input new_user_name`.

Para más info : [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

**Una ayudadita:**

Acabo de ver tu comentario en el que indicas que tendrías que hacer esto para cada botón, sí lo puedes hacer, pero hay una forma más rápida y que la puedes hacer un una simple función, Puedes utilizar `document.querySelectorAll();` este tipo de selector se utiliza como si fueras a seleccionar con `CSS` Clase = `.TuClase`, etiqueta = `span`, por atributo `input[type="text"]`. Es importante mencionar que al utilizar este forma de seleccionar obtendrás un `HTMLCollections` por lo tanto tendrás que utlizar un bucle para recorrer las etiquetas.

> Para Seleccionar el ID es con `document.querySelector('#tuId');`

En el siguiente ejemplo le agrego la clase `info` a los inputs, de esta manera selecciona con `document.querySelectorAll('.info')`; :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      
        document.getElementById('new_user_btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
        
            let info = document.querySelectorAll('.info');
               for(let i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
                    
                      //console.log(info[i].value);
                      
                      if(info[i].value == ''){ //validamos si viene vacio el campo
                          let input =info[i].getAttribute('id'); //obtenemos el texto del ID ya que se asemeja al texto que aparece en el Label.
                            input = input.replace(/_/g, ' '); //reemplamos los guiones bajos para que se paresca lo más posible al texto del Label
                          alert('El campo '+input+' es obligatorio'); //mandamos un ALert para indicarle que campo es obligatorio o está vacio.
                          return false;
                      }
               
               }
        
        })


    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="users.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lykmapipo/themify-icons@0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="new_user pt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                <!-- nombre, apellido email telefono  -->
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">New User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control info" id ="new_user_name" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control info" id="new_user_lastname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control info" id="new_user_email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control info" id="new_user_phone">
                    </div>
                    <button id="new_user_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="user_info_table pt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Last name</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Email</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Phone Nnumber</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class="text-center">
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Mark</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>@mdo</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr class="text-center">
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Jacob</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>@fat</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script src="users.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cualquier duda que tengas hazla saber.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  
    document.getElementById('new_user_btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
    
    
            var x = document.getElementById("new_user_name").value;

if(x == ""){
    console.log("esta vacio");
}else {
    console.log(x);
}
    
    })


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="users.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lykmapipo/themify-icons@0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="new_user pt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                <!-- nombre, apellido email telefono  -->
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">New User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="new_user_name" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_user_lastname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="new_user_email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New User Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="new_user_phone">
                    </div>
                    <button id="new_user_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="user_info_table pt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Last name</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Email</th>
                            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Phone Nnumber</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class="text-center">
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Mark</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>@mdo</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr class="text-center">
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Jacob</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>@fat</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script src="users.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Este sería tu parte de js, utilizando mejor jQuery

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#new_user_btn").on("click", function (e) { // detectas el click sobre el botón
                var valor = $("#new_user_name").val(); //obtienes el valor de tu input con Jquery
                var valor = document.getElementById("new_user_name").value; // con js puro

                if (valor === '') { // realizas tu validación
                    console.log("esta vacio");
                } else {
                    console.log(valor);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Esto lo estoy haciendo directamente en el HTML, solo lo tendrías que pasar a tu archivo .js

Comment: No es necesario cargar una librería para hacer lo que solicita el OP, se puede realizar simplemento con JS puro.